# API Keys Symfony and JWT Authentication

Tags: api, symfony, api-platform.com, lexikjwtauthbundle

My question is more about logical understanding than in my code itself (at the moment).
I created an API with Symfony and thanks to the tutorial on KahereCode.
I have now 2 possible clients, an application and a website.
I have some resources that must be public, for example the creation of user implies that my POST point of USER is public.
Currently, I have JWT Authentication bundle that returns a JWT token for the endpoints I have set as private.
This allows to identify the user and to limit the data to his own.
Only, isn't it possible to add an API Key in addition to this in order to identify my 2 clients and to limit the access to public resources to these two?
I would like to avoid, by leaving the endpoints completely public and vulnerable, that someone could launch a script to send data to a public POST endpoint that would overload the API, and even create unwanted users. (Well, I could still manage that with an email verification).
Can anyone help me understand how to set this up or point me to an alternative to what I'm presenting here?